# How to retrieve tensorflow datasets into numpy arrays

Tags: tensorflow

I am using tensorflow 2.0.0. I want to inspect the contents of the datats, by extracting its contents and converting to numpy arrays (maybe there are other better ways to do so). Assume a `dataset`

```
<SkipDataset shapes: {features: (4,), label: ()}, types: {features: tf.float32, label: tf.int64}>
```

Then how to extract the `features` and `label` here inside the `dataset`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `list` like in here:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds 
import tensorflow as tf

mnist = tfds.load(name="mnist", split=tfds.Split.TRAIN)
small = mnist.take(10)

print(list(small))
```

however be careful with that if your dataset is big.